# How can I fix this regex which extracts a tweet id from a Twitter URL?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will extract a tweet id from a Twitter URL.

I have this one, which works when the Twitter username has a number in it:

```
'.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)'

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Regexp.new('.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match('https://twitter.com/#!/sportsguy33/status/41257488166686720')[1]
 => "41257488166686720" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Regexp.new('.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+)',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match('http://twitter.com/#!/dailythunder/status/41382006113841153')[1]
 => "3"
```

And this one, which works when the Twitter username doesn't have a number in it

```
'.*?(\\d+)'

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Regexp.new('.*?(\\d+)',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match('https://twitter.com/#!/sportsguy33/status/41257488166686720')[1]
 => "33" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Regexp.new('.*?(\\d+)',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match('http://twitter.com/#!/dailythunder/status/41382006113841153')[1]
 => "41382006113841153"
```

How can I write one that will work in either case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the tweet ID is the last part of the url, you can use:

```
'\/(\d+)$'
```

the $ means the end of the string

Comment: I was about to post the same, except that if you're constructing the regexp between single quotes then there's no need to escape the `/` i.e. `Regexp.new('/(\d+)$').match...` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

I just released a gem [tweet_url](https://github.com/announce/tweet_url) to parse Twitter URL.

```rb
require 'tweet_url'
tweet_url = TweetUrl.parse('https://twitter.com/yukihiro_matz/status/755950562227605504')
tweet_url.status_id  #=> 755950562227605504
```

**Heads up!**
Be aware of that possibly there's a URL like https://twitter.com/sferik/status/540897316908331009/photo/1, so we cannot simply extract the last numeric part.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try out [Rubular](http://rubular.com).

> Rubular is a Ruby-based regular expression editor. It's a handy way to test regular expressions as you write them.